# Spyder debugger stops even if no breakpoint

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I am using **Spyder** with **python 3.6.5**, the debugger stops at the same line on the same file (line: 183) even if there is no breakpoint there. I have restarted the computer, spyder etc but its not fixed.

Comment: Do you have any errors? And what code is on line 183?

Comment: I don't have any error.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution. The breakpoint "red bullet" doesn't appear in the lines of code but you can use **List breakpoints** in the **DEBUG** menu. The breakpoint was showing in the list and i just did **clear this breakpoint**

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a tool named Rookout to avoid cases like this one. The breakpoint doesn't actually stop your code, so you can keep your sanity :)

Comment: he asked to help with the problem in spyder not for an other debugger

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, I followed what pam said but the **List Breakpoints** was empty. My project has several files with functions and subfunctions. And the debugger was stopping there even though there were no red bullet breakpoints

in the menu Debug the **Clear breakpoints in all files** did the thing.